# How to load payment success message without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a custom stripe payment form to process a payment. The payment and everything goes through all good but my problem is that the page is reloading and then displaying the success message. I'd like to incorporate some type of jquery ajax if possible but my method doesn't seem work. It still just reloads.

Here is the breakdown of my code. All the code is located on the same page but I'll breakdown the main areas below.

FORM:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form" class="form-horizontal">


  <div class="username-info">
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="70" placeholder="Your full name" class="name form-control" value="Test Name">
  </div>

  <div class="email-info">
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="65" placeholder="Email address" class="email form-control" value="testemail@email.com">
  </div>

  <div class="password-info">
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="70" placeholder="Password (min 6 characters)" class="password form-control" value="password123">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
    </label>
  </div>

</form
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // this identifies your website in the createToken call below
            Stripe.setPublishableKey('test_key_goes_here');

            function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    // re-enable the submit button
                    $('.submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
                    // show hidden div
                    document.getElementById('a_x200').style.display = 'block';
                    // show the errors on the form
                    $(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
                } else {
                    var form$ = $("#payment-form");
                    // token contains id, last4, and card type
                    var token = response['id'];
                    var posted = document.getElementById("post-price").value
                    // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                    form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");
                    form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='posted' value='" + posted + "' />");
                    // and submit
                    form$.get(0).submit();
                }
            }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require 'lib/Stripe.php';

$error = '';
$success = '';

if ($_POST) {
Stripe::setApiKey("test_key_goes_here");

try {
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email']))
    throw new Exception("Fill out all required fields.");
  if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
    throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
  Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $_POST['posted'],
                              "currency" => "cad",
                              "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
             "description" => $_POST['email']));
  $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong>Success!</strong> Your payment was successful.
     </div>';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
$error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
     <strong>Error!</strong> '.$e->getMessage().'
     </div>';
}
}
?>



<div class="alert alert-danger" id="a_x200" style="display: none;"> <strong>Error!</strong> <span class="payment-errors"></span> </div>
<span class="payment-success">
<?= $success ?>
<?= $error ?>
</span>
```

Also here is the jquery ajax request I was trying :

**Updated to include URL**

```
  $("#payment-form").submit(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      var url = "pricing.php";  

      $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: url,
             data: $("#payment-form").serialize(),
             success: function(data)
             {
                 alert(data);
             }
           });

  });
```

Comment: Where is your url?   Where will your POST go?

Comment: You don't have a URL, as @MisterPositive points out. The AJAX has no idea where to send this information. I'd also suggest moving the `e.preventDefault();` before the `AJAX`, granted I'm not sure that's causing any issues.

Comment: Thanks, got the URL added in now but still reloads the page. I get an alert box as well but it display all the pages code.

Comment: In your update you added a URL, but *removed the* `e.preventDefault()`. You need to include that to stop the default behavior of a page postback on form submission. Put it just before the `var url = ...` line.

Comment: Thanks got that updated in but still reloads the page unfortunately.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: no errors coming up.

Answer (score 1):

It is failing because you do not have an `url` attribute for your ajax call.

For example:

```
var url = "your url here";
$.ajax({
    "dataType": "json",
    "type": "POST",
    "url": url,
    "data": params,
    "success": function (result) {
         // Your Logic HERE
    },
    "fail": function ShowFail(xhr) { alert("Sorry! Failed"); },
    "error": function (request, status, error) {
        alert('Error=' + error + ' & Status=' + status);
    }
```

Comment: While this may be correct, I'd suggest improving your answer. As it stands, you're pointing out the problem, but not exactly solving/answering it. Perhaps an example snippet may be sufficient.

Comment: Point taken @Santi